Latest Real time Chat Message Not Display In Laravel 11 Reverb and Livewire
I am using Laravel 11 With Laravel Reverb and Laravel Livewire. When I send Message to user It not display Realtime to another user. When I change User and Open again then Display Messages. I need your help and support.
User.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'avatar',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected function casts(): array
    {
        return [
            'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
            'password' => 'hashed',
        ];
    }

    public function sendMessages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class,'sender_id');
    }

    public function receievedMessage()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class,'receiver_id');
    }
}

Message.php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Message extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'message',
        'sender_id',
        'receiver_id',
    ];


    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'sender_id');
    }

    public function receiver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'receiver_id');
    }

    public static function readMessages($senderId, ?int $receiverId)
    {
        Message::query()->where('sender_id', $senderId)->where('receiver_id', $receiverId )->update(['is_read'=>true]);
    }

    public function scopeMessageList($query, $selectedUser)
    {
        return $query->where(function(Builder $query) use($selectedUser){
            $query->where('sender_id',auth()->id())
                ->where('receiver_id',$selectedUser); 
        })->orWhere(function(Builder $query) use($selectedUser){
            $query->where('sender_id',$selectedUser)
                ->where('receiver_id',auth()->id());
        }); 
    }
}

web.php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::view('/','chat');
});

Livewire/chat.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Message;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Events\MessageEvent;

class chat extends Component
{
    public $messages = [];
    public $text;
    public $users;
    public $selectedUser;
    public $newMessage = false;
    public $userWithNewMessage = [];
    public $conversation = [];

    protected $listeners = [
        'showMessages' => 'showMessages',
    ];   
    
    public function showMessages($userId)
    {
        $this->selectedUser = User::find($userId);
        $this->messages = Message::messageList($userId)->get()->toArray();
    }

    #[On('echo:livewire_chatapp,MessageEvent')]
    public function listenForMessage($data)
    {
        $this->messages[] = $data['message'];
    }

    public function updatedMessages()
    {
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('scrollToBottom');
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        // Create a new Message instance and save it
        $message = new Message();
        MessageEvent::dispatch($this->text, $user->id, $this->selectedUser['id']);

        $this->text = null;

    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->users = User::where('id','<>',auth()->id())->get();
        return view('livewire.chat');
    }
}

livewire/chat.blade.php
<div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <h3 class="card-header">{{ __('USERS') }}</h3>
        <hr />

        <div class="col-12 row">
            <div class = "col-md-4">
                <ul class="list-group">

                    @foreach($users as $user)
                    <li wire:click="showMessages({{ $user->id }})" 
                        class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center {{(optional($selectedUser)['id']) == $user->id ? 'active' : ''}}">
                        @if(!empty($user->avatar))
                            <img src="{{ asset('avatars/' . $user->avatar) }}" alt="User Avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-right:25px;">
                        @else
                            <img src="{{ asset('avatars/default_user.png' ) }}" alt="User Avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-right:25px;">
                        @endif
                        {{$user->name}}
                        
                    </li>
                @endforeach

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-8">
            @if($selectedUser)
                <section class = "">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                                <div class="card" id="card1" style="">
                                    <div class="card-header d-flex align-items-center p-3" style="font-size:large;">
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        @if(!empty($selectedUser['avatar']))
                                            <img src="{{ asset('avatars/' . $selectedUser['avatar']) }}" alt="User Avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-right:25px;">
                                        @else
                                            <img src="{{ asset('avatars/default_user.png' ) }}" alt="User Avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;margin-right:25px;">
                                        @endif
                                        <p class="mb-0 fw-bold">{{$selectedUser['name']}}</p>
                                        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="message-body" style="height:500px;overflow: auto;flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                                            @foreach($messages as $message)
                                                @if($message['receiver_id'] == auth()->id())

                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-start mb-4">
                                                        
                                                        {{-- <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-8.webp" alt="avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center mr-2 z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;"> --}}
                
                                                        <div class="p-3 ms-3" style="border-radius:15px;background-color:rgba(57,192,237,.2);height:fit-content;">
                                                            <p class="small mb-0">{{$message['message']}}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div> 
                                                @else
                                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-end mb-4">
                                                        <div class="p-3 me-3 border" style="border-radius:15px;background-color:#fbfbfb;height:fit-content;">
                                                        <p class="small mb-0">{{$message['message']}}</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        {{-- <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-4.webp" alt="avatar" class="avatar rounded-circle d-flex align-self-center mr-2 z-depth-1" style="width:50px;height:50px;"> --}}
                                                                                        </div>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                        <div class=" row form-outline">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="textAreaExample" wire:model.debounce.100ms="text" placeholder="Type your Message...">
                                            <button wire:click="sendMessage" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"> send</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

MessageEvent.php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */

    public string $message;
    public $sender_id, $receiver_id;
    public function __construct($content, $sender_id, $receiver_id)
    {

        $this->message = $content; // Initialize the $message property
        $this->receiver_id = $receiver_id;
        $this->sender_id = $sender_id;
    
        // Save the message to the database or perform any other necessary operations
        $message = new Message();
        $message->message = $content;
        $message->receiver_id = $receiver_id;
        $message->sender_id = $sender_id;
        $message->save();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('livewire_chatapp');
    }
}



Have you run php artisan reverb:start to start the websocket server? Have you added the private channel in your routes/channels.php to authenticate to it? Check the network-tab in your browser, what do you get when its trying to connect to the websocket?

Yes I Make Following Channel In channels.php
Broadcast::channel('livewire_chatapp', function ($user) {
return true;
});
and I run Following Reverb command
php artisan reverb:start --debug
I am Getting Following Response In reverb  command after send Message
Message Received ............................................................................................................. 276199600.309868927
{
"event": "pusher:subscribe",
"data": {
"auth": "",
"channel": "livewire_chatapp"
}
}
Let Me Know What is My Mistake?
